# TypeError from "tf.keras.layers.concatenate": The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm trying to merge three layers and add it to model, but I got a `Tensor` from `tf.keras.layers.concatenate`, not a layer? How to solve this?

```
...
ipt = tf.keras.Input(shape=[10, 5])
convs = []
fs= [1, 2, 3]
for f in fs:
    conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(activation='tanh', kernel_size=f, filters=200)(ipt)
    pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(10 - fsz + 1, padding="same")(conv)
    pool = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(pool)
    convs.append(pool)
merge = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(convs, axis=1)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(ipt)
model.add(merge)
...
```

```
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Tensor("concatenate/Identity:0", shape=(None, 600), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not using the Model in the correct way. Try changing your code the following way.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

ipt = layers.Input(shape=[10, 5])
convs = []
fsz = 8
fs= [1, 2, 3]
for f in fs:
    conv = layers.Conv1D(activation='tanh', kernel_size=f, filters=200)(ipt)
    pool = layers.MaxPooling1D(10 - fsz + 1, padding="same")(conv)
    pool = layers.Flatten()(pool)
    convs.append(pool)
merge = layers.Concatenate(axis=1)(convs)

model = models.Model(inputs=ipt, outputs=merge)
model.summary()
```